# Conditional formatting with `kable` but with "%" signs

Tags: r, formatting, kable, kableextra

I love the `kable` and the `kableExtra` packages for conditional formatting of the tables and use them in Reports.  However, I see that there is no way to conditionally format the tables if you also want to include the "%" sign in them.  Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you're still stuck on this but I came across this question when dealing with the same issue and decided to post my workaround. The key is to pass the color palette function (in this case spec_color) the numeric version of the values, while using the character values with the "%" character as the input for cell_spec so that the "%" is included in the tag that cell_spec returns

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = F}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.table.format = "html")
```

```{r}
df = tibble(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  percents = c("12.7%", "14.0%", "19.2%", "20.4%", "13.2%")
)

```

```{r}
df = df %>%
  mutate(percents = cell_spec(percents, format = "html", 
                              #I first remove the "%" character, 
                              #then coerce the column to a numerical value so that
                              #the color palette function can handle it
          color = spec_color(as.numeric(str_sub(percents, end = -2L))))
         ) 

df %>% kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>% kable_styling()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scales::percent()` when creating your table like so:

````
    ---
title: "test"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(scales)

df <- diamonds

tabl1 <- df %>% group_by(  cut)    %>% summarise(n = n())
names(tabl1) <- c("Count of Cut", "n")
tabl1$perc <- scales::percent(tabl1$n / sum(tabl1$n))

```


```{r  , message= FALSE, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}

kable(tabl1)
```
````

Result:

[image: Leads to this output]

Comment: But I want to also mark all entries below 10% in red. That is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

@heck1 had a great answer, I did not know about that package. In the future, it would be helpful if you included sample data, what you have tried, and your desired result. Based on your comment, I think you are looking for something like this (below). Of course, you can change the column names and make other modifications you see fit.

````
---
title: "test"
output: word_document
---

  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- diamonds

tabl1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(perc = round(n / sum(n), 3)*100,
         cut = cell_spec(cut, color = ifelse(perc < 10, "red", "black")),
         perc = paste0(perc, "%"))

```

```{r  , message= FALSE, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}

kable(tabl1, escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
````